# How to synch audio with video when both tracks are from same source?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, file-format, compositing-nodes

I am using the VSE in Blender 2.80 on Windows 10 to add cards to an existing video in MP4 format that is about 20 minutes long. I placed my cards and have chosen the following settings:

[image]

These are the settings of the original video file:

[image]

I changed the Blender audio Bitrate first to 130 but noticed it was "off" from the video. The lips of the speaker don't quite match. Then I read that powers of 2 were useful so I changed it to 128. I also tried The MPEG-4 container but after hitting "render animation" nothing would happen. I also tried FFmpeg video codec #1 but my video player (Matroska) was unable to read the sample animation I rendered from it. Changing the quality settings and keyframe intervals alternate between making the file unreadable and not having any noticeable change. Changing "Output Quality" to "Lossless" gives me a file with audio but no video.

What do I need to do in order to have the audio match the video as closely as I can to the original video file?

Answer (score 0):

I you loose sync between video and audio, generally the reasons can be:

1) you didn't match the frame rate (in your case 29,97)

[image]

2) you didn't match the audio sample rate (in your case 48 KHz), in the preferences

[image]

The others parameters are a matter of quality/file weight, not about Sync.